# Can't delete app data on iOS, appears after reinstall

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, data-synchronization

I've got an app installed on my phone (its name is unrelated for now). The accounts I'm logged in within the app are displayed on the first screen of the app. For some reason this data is still there after removing and reinstalling the app.

Since iOS warns me that "Deleting this app will also delete its data." I believe this shouldn't be the case.

Things I've tried to permanently get rid of the app data and start with a clean slate:

- Removing the app, then reinstalling.
- Rebooting between these steps.
- Turning off the backup for the app in Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > Manage Storage > Backups > device, and switching the backup off for the app.
- Rebooting after this.
- Forcing a backup after this.
- Removing the whole backup for the device, and turning backup off.
- Removing backup of other devices (that had the account logged in).
- Hiding the app purchase in the App Store and repurchasing it.
- Restarting before installing again.
- There is no iCloud Drive directory for the app.
- I couldn't find related entry in the iCloud Keychain.

On a new iOS device under my Apple ID I can install this app and the account is not there. But it is there for devices that have logged in in this app.

The app is Duolingo and it had this problem for years. After an account name/email/password change the old account name is stuck and it doesn't let me log in with the new details.

I can't get rid of some app data and it activates a bug in the app. But anyways I believe this shouldn't be happening and is a bug with iOS.

How can I get rid of the app data permanently? Is there a local keychain that I couldn't view or edit?

iOS version: 15.1 on iPhone 11 Pro, and iPad Air 4

Comment: "Deleting this app will also delete its data" - that is it data on the iPhone. (not a bug in iOS). But it does not delete data in iCloud - some of which is not visible in iCloud Drive. I have iOS apps deleted years ago for which I can see hidden folders in iCloud on a Mac - but I can't remove them! I don't have a simple answer for you.

Comment: @Gilby in this case there is no iCloud Drive directory for the app. iCloud is off for this application. There should be no backup/sync for this app, I have turned it off. Something is stored and restored on the device.

Answer (score 2):

The information you mention is stored in the Keychain. The Keychain is first and foremost stored locally on the device, but it can also be synced across devices using the iCloud Keychain feature.

There's no viewer on the iPhone for showing you what's in the Keychain, besides the information shown to you by the original app developer (i.e. the view you mention inside Duolingo in this case).

There's really no Apple-provided way of deleting individual pieces of information from the keychain. So unless the Duolingo developers provide you with that option, it is practically possible.

Instead you can delete the whole Keychain from the phone by erasing all contents and settings on the device. That is a quite destructive option unfortunately.

For a practical solution, I would contact Duolingo support to see if they can help you in getting the issue with the changed account name resolved.