# How to delete app data from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, keychain

I have an app that I downloaded some time ago and later deleted. When I reinstall the app now, it automatically prompts me to sign in into the account from the previous install. Aside from factory resetting the phone, is there any way to ensure I delete the app data as well when I delete the app?

I tried deleting the app and deleting the app entry in keychain, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need. All app data on an iPhone or iPad is deleted at the same time as the app unless data is stored in iCloud.

Two “exceptions” to app data are persistent app install identifiers are allowed to exist so app developers can tell an app was installed before as well as iCloud and keychain items.  All of these coupled with a server the app calls to can persist app data that’s not stored on device.

Comment: Are you sure? The app is recovering state somehow. How would I delete this state?

Comment: I would need to know the iOS version and the app being used to do that. Can you edit the post to show that?

Comment: This has happened over multiple apps and multiple versions (ex. [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431847), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462383), [3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175897), etc.)